# How to hide/redirect the author page

Tags: templates, redirect, page-template, author, wp-redirect

I have a website where I let people subscribe. I would like to only show the author page for actual authors who have written a post. I wrote this code that checks for post the problem is I can't use a `wp_redirect` or include a template that uses it because then I get everyones favorite "cannot redifine headers header" message. I could display a "User has no post message but I think redirecting them to the main author page is a better option.

```
if ( is_author() ) : ?>

    <?php $id = get_query_var( 'author' );

    $post_count = get_usernumposts($id);
    if($post_count <= 0){ 
                 //This line could also be wp_redirect 
                 include( STYLESHEETPATH .'/author-redirect.php');
                 exit;
      }
endif;?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this at an earlier moment by hooking into the right action, like `template_redirect`, which fires right before the template will be displayed.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse14047_template_redirect' );
function wpse14047_template_redirect()
{
    if ( is_author() ) {
        $id = get_query_var( 'author' );
        // get_usernumposts() is deprecated since 3.0
        $post_count = count_user_posts( $id );
        if ( $post_count <= 0 ) { 
            //This line could also be wp_redirect 
            include( STYLESHEETPATH .'/author-redirect.php' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, What's up with that function name I know you don't want to conflict with other plugins but that name just seems illogical :)

Comment: @BandonRandon: This is WordPress Stack Exchange question number 14047. I create a plugin every time I test some code, this helps me keep them apart. Sometimes I see a question that contains code with other question numbers in them, which gives me a hint into the thought process of the author. And I hope to once see some `wpseXXXX` functions in the official plugin repository, that would make me proud :-)

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering how this code must change to hide a specific author but also all things related, like posts, comments and their author page. I created a new question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20381/plugin-to-hide-all-things-related-of-a-user-from-the-public I thing is a nice-to-have idea.