# Plugin to restrict login and unpublish content from an author

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I am looking for a plugin or a code that will allow admin to select an author and "ban" him from logging in the system and also to unpublish his posted content until the admin decide to allow the entrance again.

This should include posts, author page and comments if it is possible.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [User Control](http://www.iwebux.com/disableenable-wordpress-users/) Plugin